# sql create table with condition that 2 columns cannot have equal values

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

How can I write a condition in a create table statement to say 2 columns cannot be equal?

```
CREATE table Example(
    sendId integer,
    recieveId integer,
    **!sendId cannot equal recieveId**

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a check constraint:

```
CREATE table Example(
    sendId integer,
    recieveId integer,
    constraint not_equal check (sendid <> recieveId)
);
```

As your columns allow null values, you might want to take care of that too:

```
CREATE table Example(
    sendId integer,
    recieveId integer,
    constraint not_equal check (coalesce(sendid,0) <> coalesce(recieveId,0))
);
```

That treats `NULL` as `0` maybe using a different value that could never occur might be more appropriate.

Depending on your DBMS product, you could also use the standard operator `is distinct from`

```
constraint not_equal check (sendid is distinct from receiveid)
```

Comment: I'm still being allowed to insert equal values in my actual table even with the check condition added. Could it be because they are foreign keys? I am using a php page with a prepare statement and bind param to insert values.

Comment: @user2892730: [it certainly works](http://rextester.com/LJGJ28825) which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: @user2892730: MySQL doesn't support check constraints.

Comment: Darn so am I out of luck then? I wanted to write the condition in MYSQL but I can write it on my php code instead if that's the case. Thank you for the explanation regardless. It's appreciated.

Comment: @user2892730: you can always upgrade to Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `check` constraint:

```
create table Example (
    sendId integer,
    receiveId integer,
    constraint chk_example_sendId_receiveId check (sendId <> receiveId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `check` constraint :

```
constraint chk_sendId_receiveId check (sendId <> receiveId)
```